# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript, template-engine

I am trying to build a template builder using http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating

My html has this script tag

```
<script type="text/html" id="item_tmpl">
   <div>
   <div class="grid_1 alpha right">
   </div>
    <div class="grid_6 omega contents">
  <p><b><a href="/<%=AdTitle%>"><%=AdTitle%></a>:</b> <%=AdTitle%></p>
  </div>
 </div>
</script>

<script src="${URLUtils.staticURL('/js/shoptheAd.js')}"type="text/javascript"></script>
The Script contains the following code  
        (function(app){
       if (app) {
       var cache = {};
       this.tmpl = function tmpl(str, data){
        // Figure out if we're getting a template, or if we need to
        // load the template - and be sure to cache the result.
        var fn = !/\W/.test(str) ?
          cache[str] = cache[str] ||
             tmpl(document.getElementById(str).innerHTML) :
          // Generate a reusable function that will serve as a template
          // generator (and which will be cached).
          new Function("obj",
            "var p=[],print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};" +

            // Introduce the data as local variables using with(){}
            "with(obj){p.push('" +

            // Convert the template into pure JavaScript
            str
              .replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
              .split("<%").join("\t")
              .replace(/((^|%>)[^\t]*)'/g, "$1\r")
              .replace(/\t=(.*?)%>/g, "',$1,'")
              .split("\t").join("');")
              .split("%>").join("p.push('")
              .split("\r").join("\\'")
          + "');}return p.join('');");

        // Provide some basic currying to the user
        return data ? fn( data ) : fn;
      };
      var sitecoresuggestions = {
        "suggestions": [
            {
                "AdTitle": "CheckAd",
                "AdDescription": "",
                "AdImageUrl": "http://demo-kiehls.loreal.photoninfotech.com/~/media/Advertisement Images/emma-watson-3.ashx",
                "Count": 2,
                "Hit": 0
            },
            {
                "AdTitle": "CheckAd",
                "AdDescription": "",
               "AdImageUrl": "http://demo-kiehls.loreal.photoninfotech.com/~/media/Advertisement Images/kate2.ashx",
                "Count": 2,
                "Hit": 0
            }
        ]
    } ;
      var show_user = tmpl("item_tmpl"), html = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < sitecoresuggestions.suggestions.length; i++ ) {
      html += show_user( sitecoresuggestions.suggestions[i] );
    }
         console.log(html);
        } else {
            // namespace has not been defined yet
            alert("app namespace is not loaded yet!");
        }
    })(app);
        When the show_user = tmpl("item_tmpl")  is executed  
      i get the error TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

on debugging i have figured out that  due to some reason

```
      <script type="text/html" id="item_tmpl">
      <div>
     <div class="grid_1 alpha right">
     </div>
     <div class="grid_6 omega contents">
    <p><b><a href="/<%=AdTitle%>"><%=AdTitle%></a>:</b> <%=AdTitle%></p>
     </div>
   </div>
   </script>
```

does not get loaded in the browser any ideas why it is not getting loaded even though it is included inside the head tag or any other pointers for the cause of the error

Comment: John Resig has blogged about this on http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/ and it  is a fairly popular engine per  the views on internet.

Comment: the code you've shown never actually inserts the content anywhere.

Comment: var show_user = tmpl("item_tmpl"), html = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < sitecoresuggestions.suggestions.length; i++ ) {
      html += show_user( sitecoresuggestions.suggestions[i] );
    }
         console.log(html);

Comment: Right, you are logging it, but not inserting it into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for pointing,  it looks like  when i include the <script id="item_tmpl" type="text/html">...in the head it does not get rendered and i ahve to use the body for it to work properly, I will continue working on this tomorrow and update my findings as it  very late my time

Answer (score 2):

Per the post:

> Quick tip: Embedding scripts in your page that have a unknown content-type (such is the case here - >the browser doesn't know how to execute a text/html script) are simply ignored by the browser - and >by search engines and screenreaders. It's a perfect cloaking device for sneaking templates into >your page. I like to use this technique for quick-and-dirty cases where I just need a little >template or two on the page and want something light and fast.

So the page doesn't actually render the HTML, and I would assume you would only have reference to it in the page so that you can extract and apply to other objects or items.  And as the blogger states you would use it like:

```
var results = document.getElementById("results");
results.innerHTML = tmpl("item_tmpl", dataObject);
```